# Cache does not work properly

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser-cache

im using HTML5 feature cache manifest and it seems to be not working properly when i am offline and trying to access the webpage. Problem is that it tries to get jquery library from google website, although it should be cached. As result webpage does not work properly due to absence of jquery libraries
Here is my webpage:
http://www.tud.ttu.ee/web/Evald.Tali/movies/
Supposed to load offline.html when offline

Here is my cache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#updated on 22/2/2015 7:10PM
#updated cache, added links to jquery
CACHE:
index.html
CSSfile.css
script.js
jquery-1.11.2.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css
offline.html
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js
OFFLINE:
/ /offline.html
NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: Found a mistake too, it should be FALLBACK instead of OFFLINE. Glad there is a tool like www.manifest-validator.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the cache works for same origin resources only. You can't specify external files in your cache manifest. See the answer here for more information:

[App cache manifest on CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479319/app-cache-manifest-on-cdn)